# Perl if equals sign

Tags: perl, equals-operator

I need to detect if the first character in a file is an equals sign (`=`) and display the line number. How should I write the `if` statement?

```
$i=0;

while (<INPUT>)  {
    my($line) = $_;
    chomp($line);
    $findChar = substr $_, 0, 1;    

    if($findChar == "=")
    $output = "$i\n";

    print OUTPUT $output;
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Idiomatic perl would use a regular expression (`^` meaning beginning of line) plus one of the dreaded builtin variables which happens to mean "line in file":

```
while (<INPUT>) {
    print "$.\n" if /^=/;
}
```

See also [perldoc -v '$.'](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24.)

Answer (score 8):

Use `$findChar eq "="`.  In Perl:

- `==` and `!=` are numeric comparisons.  They will convert both operands to a number.
- `eq` and `ne` are string comparisons.  They will convert both operands to a string.

Yes, this is confusing.  Yes, I still write `==` when I mean `eq` **ALL THE TIME**.  Yes, it takes me forever to spot my mistake too.

Comment: @Zaid: I do `use strict;` but not warnings, since in my past experiences they're usually not that helpful.  Maybe Perl's warnings mechanism has become less noisy and more accurate lately...

Comment: I do not understand your logic: You say `warnings` is not useful. Yet, it would tell you about an error you say you commit **ALL THE TIME**. And, no, the distinction between `eq` and `==` is not confusing. Would you rather Perl had `strcmp`, `strncasecmp` etc?

Comment: @Sinan: Whoa, calm down. I'm saying in my past experiences, dating back almost ten years, it's not been useful to me.  Probably because in the versions of Perl I was using many years ago it wasn't very accurate, so it trained me to avoid using it.  I haven't really revisited it since then.

Comment: I am not sure what about my comment indicates I am not calm.

Answer (score 1):

1. It looks like you are not using [strict](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [warnings](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html). Use them, especially since you do not know Perl, you might also want to add [diagnostics](http://perldoc.perl.org/diagnostics.html) to the list of must-use pragmas.
2. You are keeping track of the input line number in a separate variable `$i`. Perl has various builtin variables documented in [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html). Some of these, such as `$.` are very useful use them.
3. You are using `my($line) = $_;` in the body of the `while` loop. Instead, avoid `$_` and assign to `$line` directly as in `while ( my $line = <$input> )`.
4. Note that bareword filehandles such as `INPUT` are package global. With the exception of the `DATA` filehandle, you are better off using [lexical filehandles](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html#Indirect-Filehandles) to properly limit the scope of your filehandles.
5. In your posts, include sample data in the `__DATA_` section so others can copy, paste and run your code without further work.

With these comments in mind, you can print all lines that do not start with `=` using:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

while (my $line = <DATA> ) {
    my $first_char = substr $line, 0, 1;
    if ( $first_char ne '=' ) {
        print "$.:$first_char\n";
    }
}
__DATA__
=
=
a
=
+
```

However, I would be inclined to write:

```
while (my $line = <DATA> ) {
    # this will skip blank lines
    if ( my ($first_char) = $line =~ /^(.)/ ) {
        print "$.:$first_char\n" unless $first_char eq '=';
    }
}
```